# Tabelizer Plugin not showing collapsible image on level 4 - using MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that contains a list of Organisations - By making use of the Tabelizer plugin, it allows me to make my table collapsible based on levels - It works perfect, except that my 4th level does not contain the collapsible image... Has anyone worked with this before and have any idea why its doing this?

The link to this plugin: http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Multilevel-Collapsible-Table-Rows-Tabelizer.html

Here is my table that consists of the levels:

[image]

Here is my code that loops down levels(Instead of using level 0, I just add 1 to it so that he levels start at 1 instead of 0):

```
<table id="table1" class="controller table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
                            <tr data-level="header" class="header" style="background-color: #00b8ce; color: white;">
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ParentOrganisationId)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentId)
                                </th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            @{

                                foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr data-level="@item.DepartmentLevel" id="level_@(item.DepartmentLevel + "_" + item.OrganisationId)">
                                        <td class="data">
                                            @{
                                                var options = new AjaxOptions()
                                                {
                                                    HttpMethod = "Get",
                                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith,
                                                    UpdateTargetId = "listofOrganisation"
                                                };
                                            }

                                            @Ajax.ActionLink(item.Name, "EditOrganisation", new { id = item.OrganisationId }, options)
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="data">
                                            @if (item.ParentOrganisationId != null)
                                            {

                                                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FirstOrDefault(xc => xc.OrganisationId == item.ParentOrganisationId.Value).Name)
                                            }
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="data">
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Departments.DepartmentId == item.DepartmentId).Departments.Name)
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-center">
                                            <button type="submit" onclick="deleteOrganisation('@item.OrganisationId')" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger text-center">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>


                                                }
                            }
                        </table>
```

The below image shows the setup, but the area highlighted in yellow shows the collapsible image that is missing.

[image]

ANyone used this plugin before and/or experienced the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue and it was in the place I last expected it to be(Even though now in hind-sight, its very logical)...

In the css class(Which I didnt provide as it was too big and I figured it was not important...which I was dead wrong) - It seems that for some reason my 4th Level expander(this is the image) was being hidden. I added the following line in my tabelizer.min.css file and it worked:

```
table.controller .l4 .expander{display:inline;}
```

This plugin is great I must admit! BUT - It says "Multi-level", which is true, but not when it comes to the CSS side of things. So if you want to add more levels, like I needed to, you will need to modify the CSS file to accommodate the styling for the additional levels.

So here is my CSS file code incase anyone has the same issue and requires a quick copy and paste, which I thought I would provide now:

```
table.controller{border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;font:14px/24px Roboto,sans-serif}
table.controller .control{font:14px 'Open Sans'}
table.controller td{padding:0;border:0 solid red}
table.controller .line{position:relative;height:24px;width:15px;float:left}
table.controller .line .vert{width:1px;height:100%}
table.controller .line .horz{position:absolute;top:50%;width:10px;height:1px}
table.controller .line.level1 .horz,table.controller .line.level1 .vert{background-color:#FF2A02}
table.controller .line.level2 .horz,table.controller .line.level2 .vert{background-color:#2BC6CC}
table.controller .line.level3 .horz,table.controller .line.level3 .vert{background-color:#098EE7}
table.controller .line.level4 .horz,table.controller .line.level4 .vert{background-color:#ff6a00}
table.controller .line.level5 .horz,table.controller .line.level5 .vert{background-color:#4cff00}
table.controller .line.level6 .horz,table.controller .line.level6 .vert{background-color:#ff00dc}
table.controller tr.hidden{display:none}
table.controller .expander{margin-right:10px}
table.controller .l1 .control{width:10px;min-height:100%}
table.controller .l2 .control{width:30px;min-height:100%}
table.controller .l3 .control{width:60px;min-height:100%}
table.controller .l4 .control{width:90px;min-height:100%}
table.controller .l5 .control{width:120px;min-height:100%}
table.controller .l6 .control{width:150px;min-height:100%}
table.controller .l7 .control{width:180px;min-height:100%}
table.controller .l1.contracted .control .line.level1,
table.controller .l2.contracted .control .line.level2,
table.controller .l3.contracted .control .line.level3,
table.controller .l4.contracted .control .line.level4,
table.controller .l5.contracted .control .line.level5,
table.controller .l6.contracted .control .line.level6,
table.controller .l7 .expander{display:none}
table.controller .l4 .expander{display:inline;}
table.controller .label{margin-right:30px}
table.controller td.data{text-align:center;min-width:90px}
table.controller .control,table.controller .expander,table.controller .label{float:left}
table.controller .contracted .expander{width:10px;height:20px;background-position:0 5px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:10px 10px;background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,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)}
table.controller .expanded .expander{width:10px;height:20px;background-position:0 5px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:10px 10px;background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,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)}
table.controller .childless .expander,table.controller .control .line.level1 .horz{display:none}
table.controller .l1-first .control .line.level1 .horz{display:block}
table.controller .l1-last .control .line.level1 .horz{display:block;width:10px;height:1px}
table.controller .l1-first .control .line.level1 .vert{bottom:0;position:absolute;width:1px;height:50%}
table.controller .l1-last .control .line.level1 .vert{width:1px;height:50%}
table.controller .control .line.level2 .horz{display:none}
table.controller .l2-first .control .line.level2 .horz{display:block}
table.controller .l2-last .control .line.level2 .horz{display:block;width:10px;height:1px}
table.controller .l2-first .control .line.level2 .vert{bottom:0;position:absolute;width:1px;height:50%}
table.controller .l2-last .control .line.level2 .vert{width:1px;height:50%}
table.controller .control .line.level3 .horz{display:none}
table.controller .l3-first .control .line.level3 .horz{display:block}
table.controller .l3-last .control .line.level3 .horz{display:block;width:10px;height:1px}
table.controller .l3-first .control .line.level3 .vert{bottom:0;position:absolute;width:1px;height:50%}
table.controller .l3-last .control .line.level3 .vert{width:1px;height:50%}
table.controller .control .line.level4 .horz{display:none}
table.controller .l4-first .control .line.level4 .horz{display:block}
table.controller .l4-last .control .line.level4 .horz{display:block;width:10px;height:1px}
table.controller .l4-first .control .line.level4 .vert{bottom:0;position:absolute;width:1px;height:50%}
table.controller .l4-last .control .line.level4 .vert{width:1px;height:50%}
table.controller .control .line.level5 .horz{display:none}
table.controller .l5-first .control .line.level5 .horz{display:block}
table.controller .l5-last .control .line.level5 .horz{display:block;width:10px;height:1px}
table.controller .l5-first .control .line.level5 .vert{bottom:0;position:absolute;width:1px;height:50%}
table.controller .l5-last .control .line.level5 .vert{width:1px;height:50%}
table.controller .control .line.level6 .horz{display:none}
table.controller .l6-first .control .line.level6 .horz{display:block}
table.controller .l6-last .control .line.level6 .horz{display:block;width:10px;height:1px}
table.controller .l6-first .control .line.level6 .vert{bottom:0;position:absolute;width:1px;height:50%}
table.controller .l6-last .control .line.level6 .vert{width:1px;height:50%}
```